# How to hide "quodlibet wants to inhibit shortcuts" message

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10, usability, quodlibet

Ever since upgrading to 17.10, whenever I click on the time elapsed bar in quodlibet (to manually change the current track playback time), I get a 
warning message that says "Quod Libet wants to inhibit shortcuts. You can restore shortcuts by pressing Shift+Ctrl+Escape." There are "Deny" and "Allow" buttons, but neither appear to do anything useful, and the message pops up *every single time* I click on the bar. It's quite annoying. How can I get around this? I honestly don't care if it's just hiding the message or automatically picking one or the other option.

I didn't post this to the quodlibet issue tracker since this seems to be an OS matter, not an application-specific problem. Of course, I could be wrong, but I figured it best to start here.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this?

Comment: Nope, still annoying me almost every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into the same issue with Evolution (many others with other programs). The reason seems to be the new default display server in Ubuntu 17.10: Wayland. Switching back to XORG as described in this [post](https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/) resolves the problem handsomely:

1. Logout as user
2. On the login page, click on the gearwheel, choose "Ubuntu on Xorg"
3. Login again

Comment: It does appear that this is an issue about Wayland interaction, but just switching to Xorg seems like a workaround, not a solution. That being said, since 18.04 is going back to Xorg, maybe it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: I see your point, it is not a solution in the strict sense. But at least the annoying messages don't appear anymore.

Comment: Now that I've upgraded to 18.04, the problem is gone. It's seems to be a Wayland issue, so hopefully that will get fixed sooner or later, but in the meantime, I'm not worrying about it.